# How to get TestClass in main method in maven project?

Tags: java, maven, junit

I have Junit5Runner class which starts Junit5 test programmatically.
It's not a maven project now, it's a simple java project with no any framework.
I need to switch to maven project, but in a maven project test classes are located inside test folder and aren't accessable from src folder.

How can I get access to test class from test folder in the main class from src folder?

Here is my Junit5Runner code.

Here I get access to CalculatorTest class.

```
public class Junit5Runner {
    SummaryGeneratingListener listener = new SummaryGeneratingListener();

    public void runOne() {
        LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
                .selectors(selectClass(CalculatorTest.class)) //I NEED TO GET THIS CLASS FROM TEST FOLDER
                .build();
        Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();
        TestPlan testPlan = launcher.discover(request);
        launcher.registerTestExecutionListeners(listener);
        launcher.execute(request);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Junit5Runner runner = new Junit5Runner();
        runner.runOne();
        TestExecutionSummary summary = runner.listener.getSummary();
        for (TestExecutionSummary.Failure failure : summary.getFailures()) {
            System.out.println(failure.getTestIdentifier().getDisplayName());
            System.out.println(failure.getException());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so ... you have unit tests IN your actual production code? Not in the separate test module?

Comment: You don't need your custom `Junit5Runner` any longer, just let Maven do the work. And if you absolutely want, put it in `src/test/...`

Comment: First why not using the command line runner of JUnit 5 ..second why implementing yourself (for learning purposes?) . To be honest the comments about: `but in a maven project test classes are located inside test folder and aren't accessable from src folder.`... I simply don't understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to put your production code int `src/main/java/<package>` and your unit tests into `src/test/java/<packageName>` and name your unit tests like `*Test.java`. If you follow that you can execute your unit tests (assumed you have added the appropriate dependencies for JUnit Jupiter in your pom file) via

```
mvn clean test
```

Full setup for JUnit Jupiter and example project can be found [here.](https://youtu.be/NVvMzy0Lin0)

Comment: Yes, really, it works, but I got an error previous time, it's strange... Ok, still, relating with your questions: `First why not using the command line runner of JUnit 5 ..second why implementing yourself (for learning purposes?)` I need to perform an ability for users to they can load threir class to my program, test it and get the result: is it correct or not..... That is why I need to run tests programmatically, but maybe you know more appropriate practice to do it?

Comment: Why should people load their classes in your program? I'm writing my tests on my own and don't load them into a separate app ? Can you explain that more in detail?

Comment: Yes, I'm creating a web service with spring boot for education purposes, I need to students has ability to check their solutions is it correct or not. Education tasks are located on a web site, students can load their solution to the web site

Comment: Ah...now that makes sense...